# Postgresql import csv failing on quoted \r\n

Tags: postgresql, import, csv

This is my first question here and I'm new to Postgres as well.

I'm trying to import a csv file into an existing table that has an identical structure. Using the PgAdmin4 Import/Export data... I get this ERROR:

> extra data after last expected column
> CONTEXT:  COPY imp_context, line 51: "-1788458856363711248,64FB6CD9-9FB9-4476-BF19-036DFCA10BD7,Deposit,,,,,,,,,grayish brown,,,,,,,06/03/..."

In that spot, line 51, there is a multiline text field with `\r\n` separating the lines and the whole field encased in quotes in a valid csv format (I ran the file through an online csv validator and it is valid). See the image below of the csv data where I highlighted the end of the record. Can anyone see a problem in the file or help with the import?

[image]

Comment: If the CSV is valid, the next step is to check if it has the same number of columns than the destination table. In this case, according to the error message, the file has more columns.

Comment: Embarrassingly, yes, that's it. The csv has one more column. Thanks, Daniel